# How to nullify the fields that fail validation and save the domain?

Tags: grails

Suppose there is a domain as defined below.

```
class Book {
    String title        
    Author author
}
```

Now, i save an instance of this domain. The author domain has some constraints. So, during save the validation for author fails now instead of not saving the whole domain i want to nullify the author(The author can be null) and save the title string as it was. In other words how do i nullify any number of fields whose validation failed and save rest of the properties values? Is there a convenient way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of  following :

1. In `beforeInsert hook` do something like below:

   ```
   def beforeInsert() {
        this.validate()
        if(this.hasErrors()){
        // get all errors and iterate through it and set the field to null for same
       }
   }
   ```
2. While saving the domain you could use

> domain.save(validate:false)

Thanks!!